# bash: how for loop sorts files when iterating

Tags: bash, sort, for

What is the default behavior of `for` loop in terms of sorting when listing files in a directory?

e.g.

```
for sqlfile in *.sql; do mysql -u root -p pass < sqlfile; done
```

Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It does not sort **ever**. It is the glob (`*.sql`) that is doing the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

According to `man bash`'s section on "Pathname Expansion":

> If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded  as  a pattern,  and replaced with an **alphabetically sorted** list of filenames matching the pattern […]

This sorting depends on the value of `$LC_COLLATE`:

> This  variable determines the collation order used when sorting the results of pathname expansion […]

As you can see from the above, this has nothing to do with the `for` loop. Globs can be used in many ways, and their expansion is always sorted.

Comment: `for` does not sort ever. It is the glob (`*.sql`) that is doing the sorting.

Comment: Sure, I'm just explaining how the sorting that happens in the `for` loop works.

Comment: For me to accept the answer, the comment of ctrl-alt-delor on the glob should be added.

Comment: +1 for the LC_COLLATE observation.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops don't sort, they give you the values in exactly the order they were presented:

```
$ for x in b a c ; do echo $x ; done
b
a
c
```

Globs, on the other hand, do sort alphabetically, regardless of if you use them in a `for` or anywhere else:

```
$ touch b a c
$ echo *
a b c
```